# ScalaTest: conditionally ignore a WordSpec test

Tags: scala, scalatest

ScalaTest WordSpec allows tests to be ignored like this:

```
class MySpec extends WordSpec {
  "spec" should {
    "ignore test" ignore {fail("test should not have run!")}
  }
}
```

Which is great, but I don't want to forget about ignored tests. So I would like the ignore behaviour to expire after a provided date. At which point the test would run as normal and either: 1) pass (hopefully) or 2) remind me that it is still broken.

To achieve this I'm trying to extend the WordSpec DSL to support an `ignoreUntil` function. This would accept a string expiry date and ignore the test if the date still in the future, else run the test.

My test spec would then look like:

```
class MySpec extends EnhancedWordSpec {
  "spec" should {
    "conditionally ignore test" ignoreUntil("2099-12-31") {fail("test should not have run until the next century!")}
  }
}
```

I've implemented the `ignoreUntil` function here:

```
class EnhancedWordSpec extends WordSpecLike {
  implicit protected def convertToIgnoreUntilWrapper(s: String) = new IgnoreUntilWordSpecStringWrapper(s)

  protected final class IgnoreUntilWordSpecStringWrapper(wrapped: String) {
    // Run test or ignore, depending if expiryDate is in the future
    def ignoreUntil(expiryDate: String)(test: => Any): Unit = ???
  }
}
```

However `sbt test` gives me the following compilation error:

```
MySpec.scala:3: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Char
[error]  required: String
[error]         "ignoreUntil" ignoreUntil("2099-12-31"){fail("ignoreUntil should not have run!")}
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Why exactly does the compiler not like the signature of `ignoreUntil` function?

Is there some voodoo with implicits going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many arguments. 
Implicit on string was not able to be resolved properly.

Two options:

- add a dot after "test name"
- move both `expireDate` and `test: => Any` parameters to one paramter set.

  `"conditionally ignore test".ignoreUntil("2099-12-31")  {`
           `fail("test should not have run until the next century!") }`

Comment: I had already considered the single parameter set and discounted it because it changes the structure of the test a little more than I'd like.

But I like your solution of using the explicit dot character in the call to `ignoreUntil`.  That seems like a less intrusive fix to me.

Thanks for explaining the error and suggesting the solutions.